# Why does Lucene (Hibernate Search) ignore my own operator?

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I recently updated my Hibernate Search to 5.0.0.Alpha4, which uses Lucene 4.8.1.

I still use the same codes to create my search query as before (I used Lucene 3.3 before updating, it was a really old version:)). But I noticed a problem, that the new version just ignores my operator and uses the default operator all the time, however the codes worked fine in the older version:

For Example: Now I set "AND" as default Operator. I just typed "java or php" in the search field. And I made a breakpoint at the line of queryParser.parse(searchString). It tells me that my searchString is now "java or php", which is correct. But the created searchQuery after queryParser.parse() is:

```
+(title:java) +(title:php)
```

Which means that Lucene deals my searchString as "AND" LOGIC!

I don't know if it is a bug of newer Lucene or just i did something wrong.

Here are the codes:

```
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(
            Version.LUCENE_47);
MultiFieldQueryParser queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(
    Version.LUCENE_47,
    mySearchFields,
    analyzer);
queryParser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
queryParser.setDefaultOperator(myDefaultOperator);
queryParser.setAutoGeneratePhraseQueries(true);
Query searchQuery = queryParser.parse(searchString);

FullTextQuery jpaQuery = getFullTextEntityManager()
    .createFullTextQuery(searchQuery, entities);
jpaQuery.setMaxResults(ORACLE_MAXIMUM_ELEMENTS_IN_EXPRESSION);
```

Comment: I'll assume you aren't actually searching for "A AND B".  Is this the whole story?  What is the `booleanQuery` for?  Also, try seeing what `searchQuery.toString()` looks like before you run the query, might not be what you were expecting for some reason.

Comment: @femtoRgon At the breakpoint of queryParser.parse(searchString) I checked searchString is still "A AND B". But it is really a good idea to remove the part of BooleanQuery to test it again. I will try it right now. Thank you!

Comment: `searchString` isn't really what I was asking about.  `Query.toString` won't just kick back the string passed in to `QueryParser`.  I want to know what the generated query actually looks like, after parsing and analysis.  Also, if this is your *actual* code, removing the `BooleanQuery` won't solve your problem, because it's never used.  Is that different in the code your actually running?

Comment: @femtoRgon I just edited the question and now you will see how the created Query looks like. Yes, i just noticed that i forgot to use BooleanQuery and i don't need it anymore:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Boolean Operators *must* be in CAPS](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Boolean_operators).  That is:  `java OR php` is correct, `java or php` is *not*.

To explain exactly what is going on, without `or` being in caps, it's treated as another term.  With `AND` being the default operator, this makes it:

```
java AND or AND php
```

or, something like

```
+(title:java) +(title:or) +(title:php)
```

However, `or` is a standard stop word, and so it will be eliminated during analysis of the query, and you are left with simply:

```
+(title:java) +(title:php)
```